# How to dispatch a Job to a specific queue in Lumen 5.5

Tags: php, queue, lumen

In standard a job I use this method to dispatch a Job:

```
dispatch(new PurchaseJob($trxId, $method, $params));
```

Next I want to dispatch another Job to send email, but I want to split it to another separate queue.
From what I read on Laravel 5.5 docs I could do this:

```
SendEmailJob::dispatch($userEmail)->onQueue('send_email');
```

But it does not seems to work on Lumen 5.5.

What could I do to make this work or is there any other method that are not stated in the docs?

Comment: Did you managed to fix it? I am also having the same problem with Lumen 5.5

Comment: Not at the moment. I still end up using the same queue.

Comment: Same Problem here ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just managed to find a way to dispatch the queue with the specified name in Lumen 5.5.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $job = (new SendFriendRequestEmail($notifiable))->onQueue('email');
    dispatch($job);
}
```

May be this [article](https://divinglaravel.com/queue-system/pushing-jobs-to-queue) will help you understand more

Comment: Thanks for sharing man! That article is a great source of queuing and very detailed.

Comment: Can you guide me in which php file this has to be done? None of the docs mention  the file. Also, does this require any changes in vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config/queue.php?

Comment: @Zoran777, Of course you need to change /config/queue.php to add another queue connection that use different tube name (in beanstalk case), then you could use the answer above and use the queue name as the parameter of onQueue()

Comment: As it turns out, in my case I had to put the above code in QueueForTransactionController.php. This is the class where the enqueuing happens.