# Job chaining in Lumen 5.5: withChain() not working how can I make it work?

Tags: php, jobs, lumen, chaining, laravel-5.5

For dispatching a single job I usually do one of these:

```
Queue::push(new ExampleJob);
```

or

```
dispatch(new ExampleJob);
```

https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues

According to the Laravel Docs a certain Job chain, where one Job depends upon the previous is done like this:

```
ExampleJob::withChain([
    new OptimizePodcast,
    new ReleasePodcast
])->dispatch();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#job-chaining

However this does not workin in Lumen (similar problem here: [How to dispatch a Job to a specific queue in Lumen 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648288/how-to-dispatch-a-job-to-a-specific-queue-in-lumen-5-5)).

How do I chain Jobs in Lumen 5.5?

Comment: Possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199476/how-to-dispatch-chained-jobs-to-a-queue-in-lumen-6/59369832

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that will work given that in Laravel 5.5 documentation, in their example under [creating jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#creating-jobs) under the Queues documentation page, it shows that it requires several traits to able use all the features:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Podcast;
use App\AudioProcessor;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $podcast;
```

Most notably is this one:

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;` which appears to be a trait that is missing from the Lumen 5.5 framework altogether.

The rest of the `Illuminate\...` traits seem to be included.

Comment: In my case, I needed to move quickly, so I just decided to use Laravel 5.5 instead, in spite of its added overhead.

But I can confirm that the chaining jobs happens to work as advertised on Laravel 5.5

Comment: As per the [Lumen Queue doc's](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues), you can dispatch a job (without the need for the Dispatchable trait) by simply calling `dispatch(new ExampleJob);`.